# How to import existing project in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a project which developed in react native using expo tool. Now I am trying to import project in expo but facing below error,

```
 F:\ProjectPath>expo start
 Starting project at F:\ProjectPath
 Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
 Error: Missing app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/
 No Expo configuration found. Are you sure this is a project directory?
```

Comment: Well, does directory you are in have app.json? Most likely you are not in the right directory. I haven't used expo CLI in Windows but if it works anything like in the mac there is a good chance that you have created a folder inside your project directory where your app actually is.